# What is the best style/syntax to use with Rhino Mocks?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, syntax, rhino-mocks, mocking

Multiple approaches exist to write your unit tests when using Rhino Mocks:

- The Standard Syntax
- Record/Replay Syntax
- The Fluent Syntax

What is the ideal and most frictionless way?

Answer (score 1):

For .NET 2.0, I recommend the record/playback model. We like this because it separates clearly your expectations from your verifications.

```
using(mocks.Record())
{
    Expect.Call(foo.Bar());
}
using(mocks.Playback())
{
    MakeItAllHappen();
}
```

If you're using .NET 3.5 and C# 3, then I'd recommend the fluent syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question!  My own preference is the for the reflection-based syntax (what I guess you mean by the Standard Syntax).  I would argue that this is the most frictionless, as it does not add much extra code: you reference the stubs directly on your interfaces as though they were properly implemented.

I do also quite like the Fluent syntax, although this is quite cumbersome.  The Record/Replay syntax is as cumbersome as the Fluent syntax (if not more so, seemingly), but less intuitive (to me at least).  I've only used NMock2, so the Record/Replay syntax is a bit alien to me, whilst the Fluent syntax is quite familiar.

However, as [this post](https://yellowduckguy.wordpress.com/2007/10/06/rhino-mocks-v3-2-new-syntax/) suggests, if you prefer separating your expectations from your verifications/assertions, you should opt for the Fluent syntax.  It's all a matter of style and personal preference, ultimately :-)